# Function call fails when I replace an inline function with a named one

Tags: javascript, function-calls

Why does the following code runs:

```
someExpression.then((result)=>{
    console.log(util.inspect(result,{depth:null}));
    return result;
}))
```

and when this function has a name it doesn't:

```
function print(result) {
    console.log(util.inspect(result,{depth:null}));
    return result;
}

someExpression.then(print(result)))
```

with error:

> ReferenceError: result is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing a function in your second example. You're executing a function and passing its result.

The proper way to do this would be:

```
someExpression.then(print)
```